# Add text from textarea to a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I want to add the text user enter in a textarea to be added to my table.

User enter type in the text in a textarea and then click on a button and then the text appears into a table.

I have to following code in my view.

```
    <p>Custom Question</p>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CustomQuestionText)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomQuestionText)
</div>
<div><p><input type="button" value="Lägg till" /></p></div>
</div>
```

And this is the table that I want the text to filled in:

```
<table id="CustomTable">
<thead><tr><th>Custom questions</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any solutions with Jquery is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(':input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        $('#CustomTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                html: $('<td/>', {
                    text: $('#CustomQuestionText').val()
                })
            })
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jHWw3/).

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to be able to remove the text I added to the table, by clicking to the row.

Comment: @ps__, very easy, you simply subscribe to the click handler of the row. I have updated my jsfiddle with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jHWw3/1/

Answer (score 4):

Give your button an ID and then use the JQuery click function to capture the textbox value and append to the table:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAppend" value="Lägg till" />


<script>
    $("#btnAppend").click(function() {
        var textboxVal = $("#CustomQuestionText").val();

        $("#CustomTable").append("<tr><td>" + textboxVal + "</td></tr>");
 });

</script>
```